# Invalid use of null error in select into from query

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT [TABLE1].*, 
  IIf(COLUMN1="I",COLUMN2,COLUMN3) AS NEWCOL1, 
  IIf([COLUMN1]="I",[COLUMN2],
      IIf([Year]>2009,[COLUMN4],[COLUMN2]+[COLUMN5]+[COLUMN6])
  ) AS NEWCOL2 
INTO [TABLE2]
FROM [TABLE1];
```

I keep getting an `"Invalid use of null"` error -- and my data in TABLE1 is not corrupted, except there are some zeros in COLUMNS 2 through 6 -- anything wrong with the structure here?

Comment: Does the `select` work on its own (no `into`)? What if you don't add columns 2, 5 and 6, but just pick one of them?

Comment: Nope -- I tried  SELECT [TABLE1].* INTO [TABLE2] FROM [TABLE1];  -- same "Invalid use of null" error

Comment: Check for the string with NZ function `Nz (varName, NULL)` of empty string the replace with `NULL`.